# Import Python Issues

Tags: python, import, directory

I've been writing in python for a couple of months now and I've never found a through explanation of how import works. I downloaded this folder with subfolders with python files in them. I'm trying to use one of these files and I'm loosing my mind. How do you properlly import a folder with all the files in it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the [python documentation on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html):

If you have a folder sound looking like that :

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
```

To import all files of effects folder :

```
from sound.effects import *
```

Note that to be able to import module, they have to contain an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if the subdirectories have a file named `__init__.py` file in them. Python will not recognize directories that do not contain these files.

Then, you will have to manually change the `PYTHONPATH`, which you can find in `sys.path`. You can find a great example [here](http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html).

Edit: I'm not 100% sure this is what you were asking for. If you want to import ALL the python files in a directory, you will have to import them one by one. For example, given a directory like so:

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    runner.py
    example.py
    language.py
```

you would have to type

```
from parent import runner, example, language
```

or

```
from parent import * # this will also import __init__
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `__init__.py` file in the directory to make it a package. In this file you import all the symbols from the underlying files.

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html (especially part 6.4 Packages) for further notes on that.

Answer (score 0):

The parent folder must be either in PYTHONPATH or the folder path indicated in a file with extension `.pth` situated in a location in your path, usually in `site-packages`.

Then your package and all folders inside it from which you have to import need to have a file named `__init__`. This file can be used for program initialization but as a starting point it can be an empty file.

For example my program folder, situated in `C:\python26` has the estructure:

```
programas\

.....package1\
.........__init__.py
.........module1.py
.........subpackage1\
.............__init__.py
.............module2.py

.....package2\
.........__init__.py
.........module3

.....__init__.py
.....lonelyscript1.py
.....lonelyscript2.py
```

file `site-packages\site.pth` contains:

```
C:\Python26\programas
```